# clang frontend command failed with exit code 70 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: xcode, cordova, meteor

This error started happening in XCode when generating an archive for my Meteor (cordova) app. I changed nothing in the app source code.

Other questions about similar errors like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45667117/clang-error-clang-frontend-command-failed-with-exit-code-70-use-v-to-see-inv/54109719) are responded by doing clean builds, a clean `npm install` etc. None worked for me. The issue even happens when doing a `git clone` and building from the source on another computer.

The complete error messages are:

```
Global variable initializer type does not match global variable type!
%struct.GPBObjcClass_t* @"OBJC_CLASS_$_GPBField"
Global variable initializer type does not match global variable type!
%struct.GPBObjcClass_t* @"OBJC_CLASS_$_GPBOption"
Global variable initializer type does not match global variable type!
%struct.GPBObjcClass_t* @"OBJC_CLASS_$_GPBEnumValue"
fatal error: error in backend: Broken module found, compilation aborted!
clang: error: clang frontend command failed with exit code 70 (use -v to see invocation)
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)
Target: arm-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
clang: note: diagnostic msg: 
********************

PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/yp/p4gh1z4x3010nqzxbg_52bqw0000gn/T/GPBType-b12118.m
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/yp/p4gh1z4x3010nqzxbg_52bqw0000gn/T/GPBType-b12118.cache
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/yp/p4gh1z4x3010nqzxbg_52bqw0000gn/T/GPBType-b12118.sh
clang: note: diagnostic msg: Crash backtrace is located in
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /Users/barts/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/clang_<YYYY-MM-DD-HHMMSS>_<hostname>.crash
clang: note: diagnostic msg: (choose the .crash file that corresponds to your crash)
clang: note: diagnostic msg:
```

Comment: did you get any solution for this?

Comment: Not yet @DivyanshuJoshi

Comment: Same problem. What could cause this?

Comment: In my case, I've narrowed it down to the push plugins I use (raix:push / phonegap-plugin-push, cordova-intercom, cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics). What is your setup, @iiro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I solved this by updating XCode from 10.1 to 11.3.1 (which is the most recent that runs on my Mojave).

This answer helped me update: [How to download Xcode DMG or XIP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file)

(The downloads did not go well on Firefox but Chrome downloaded fine.)