# Xcode 10.1 Unable to archive project

Tags: swift, xcode10.1

I want to upload my app to appstore, after getting success build I am trying to archiving my project but getting following error,

```
clang: error: clang frontend command failed with exit code 70 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvZdv.jpg)

What went wrong? Can someone help me to fix this?

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild?

Comment: Have you tried [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58370917/651409) by deleting DerivedData?

Comment: Xcode 10.1 is quite old. Did you try to update it?

Comment: It seems you are coding with Swfit 3.0 so it`s not a good idea anymore. It has been deprecated. Update your code and your XCode first.

Answer (score 1):

Remove old references by cleaning the derived data of your app.
Quit/Open Xcode & then try to archive.

PS: Update your XCode & Swift